# Order types of positive reals

Tags: lo.logic, order-theory

Suppose one has a set $S$ of positive real numbers, such that the usual numerical ordering on $S$ is a well-ordering. Is it possible for $S$ to have any countable ordinal as its order type, or are the order types that can be formed in this way more restricted than that?

Comment: A small remark: I once gave a graduate-level course in which I wanted to do transfinite induction over the countable ordinals but didn't want to spend time developing the theory of ordinals. So I defined the countable ordinals as equivalence classes of well-ordered subsets of the reals, which is the kind of thing one would like to do for the ordinals themselves but cannot because of set-theoretic paradoxes. It worked nicely and was completely rigorous.

Comment: All well-orderings are rigid as orders, and this question: mathoverflow.net/questions/9901/…  inquires more generally about other rigid suborders of the real line.

Comment: As a remark, this result is used to prove that the long line
really is a $1$-manifold.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, one can have any countable ordering. Indeed any countable totally
ordered set can be embedded in $\mathbb{Q}$. Write your ordered set as
$ \lbrace a_1,a_2,\ldots \rbrace $
and define the embedding recursively: once you have placed $a_1,\ldots,a_{n-1}$
there will always be an interval to slot $a_n$ into.

Comment: I don't get this answer.  The ordinal $\omega+1$ is an order-type that is countable, but your method of embedding won't work without some modification (if you place a_i at the rational number i, there will be no room left for the final entry).

I would recommend David checkbox gowers answer, as it actually covers all of the countable well-orderings.

Comment: It does work: $\omega+1$ is a countable set. We can write its
elements as $\omega,0,1,2,\ldots$. This is an order we can insert
them in. There is no "final" entry.

Comment: But the original question asked about all possible countable order types.  If you re-order things, you have changed the order type.  For example, if you rearrange the countable set $\omega+1$ as $\omega,0,1,2,\ldots$, your new order type is just $\omega$.

Comment: No, I have not altered the order type. All I have done is use
a bijection between $\mathbb{N}$ and the ordered set. In
$\omega+1$, $\omega$ is still the largest element -- but
it's the one you insert first. So in your example we could start
by mapping $\omega$ to $0$, then map $0$ to $-1$, then $1$ to $-1/2$
etc. The insight is that one doesn't have to insert your elements
in increasing order!

Comment: Ah, that wasn't clear from your original answer.  Now that you say that, it makes total sense.

Comment: This argument is due originally to Cantor, and is the origin of the back-and-forth method used throughout model theory. As elsewhere, the universal property here uses only "forth".

Answer (score 10):

You can get any order type. Let's assume you can get all order types up to but not including alpha, using subsets of (0,1]. If alpha=beta + 1 then squash your representation of beta and add an extra point. If alpha is a limit ordinal, choose a sequence of ordinals that converges to alpha and put the first one into (0,1/2], the second into (1/2,3/4] etc. and the result will have order type alpha.

Comment: This seems like a good answer to me, too, but I gave the checkbox to Robin's because it uses less about the structure of the ordinals: just the fact of their countability rather than a decomposition into limits and non-limits.

Answer (score 5):

To complete the picture (the obvious remaining part). If ${S\subset\mathbb R}$ is well ordered, then it is countable: indeed it has countable cofinality. Thus well-ordered subsets of **R** are *exactly* countable ordinals.

Comment: Another way to see this is to note that there is a rational
between the images of $\alpha$ and $\alpha+1$ and these rationals
are all distinct.

Comment: Yes, this is why I included "countable" already in the statement of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Using wellorderings of positive reals is actually the standard way to construct an Aronszajn tree.

Comment: I thought the "standard" method is to use 1-1 maps from the countable ordinals into $\omega$. A tree constructed in this way can't have an uncountable chain lest we map $\omega_1$ 1-1 into $\omega$.