# Monotone injection of an ordinal into $[0,1]$

Tags: set-theory, real-analysis, lo.logic

This is related to my [recent question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/41597/transfinite-induction-a-theorem-of-pedersen-and-chains-of-subalgebras-of-bh) and would provide a natural positive answer to Question 2. I am sure this must be known to experts.

> **Question:** Is there a monotone injection $(\omega_1,<) \to ([0,1],<)$ ?

Comment: What is the definition of $\omega_1$? There is a monotone injection of every countable ordinal into the unit interval, but no such injection for the first uncountable ordinal.

Comment: $\omega_1$ denotes the first uncountable ordinal.

Comment: Thus explaining Alessandro's proof. Thanks.

Comment: You might also see
http://mathoverflow.net/questions/25100/order-types-of-positive-reals/25101

Comment: (On the other hand, for any countable ordinal $\alpha$, ${\mathbb Q}$ contains subsets order-isomorphic to $\alpha+1$ that are closed as subsets of ${\mathbb R}$.)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

No, because you could use it to construct an injective map $\omega_1\to\mathbb{Q}$, mapping $\alpha<\omega_1$ to some rational number between $\alpha$ and $\alpha+1$.

Comment: Glad to be helpful.

Answer (score 6):

There is a far reaching generalization of this due to Friedman and Shelah. Suppose $X$ is a Borel set in a Polish space and $<$ is a linear order of $X$ that is a Borel subset of $X\times X$. Then there is no order preserving map from $\omega_1$ into $(X,<)$.

The Friedman-Shelah result follows from a later structure theorem of Harrington and Shelah
who proved that for any such Borel linear order $(X,<)$ there is a Borel measurable order preserving
map into ${\bf R}^\alpha$ for some countable ordinal $\alpha$ where ${\bf R}^\alpha$ is ordered lexicographically.  The arguments for $[0,1]$ above can be generalized to show
that ${\bf R}^\alpha$ has no $\omega_1$-chains.

Answer (score 5):

Let me add a slightly different argument to Alessandro's quick and clever solution. 
Assume that $f:(\omega_1,<)\to([0,1],<)$ is an order preserving map. Let $X$ be the range of $f$. Set $a=\sup(X)$, the least upper bound of $X$. Now $X\cap [0,a]$ is uncountable while $X\cap [0,a-\frac{1}{n}]$ is countable for $n=1,2,\dots,$ an impossibility. Question: where did I use that $f$ is o.p.?

Comment: `$X\cap [0,a-1/n]$` can be uncountable if `$f$` is not o.p. For example, choose an uncountable subset `$A$` of `$\omega_1$` such that its complement `$A^c$` is uncountable as well. Then define `$f(A)=1$ and `$f(A^c)=1/2$` (this is not injective, but it should not be difficult to construct an injective `$f$` using the same idea).