# Is every countable well-order embeddable in \mathbb{R}?

Tags: order-theory, set-theory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Order types of positive reals](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/25100/order-types-of-positive-reals)

The title is self-explanatory.

Comment: Yes. See the answers to this identical question - http://mathoverflow.net/questions/25100/order-types-of-positive-reals

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is yes. Choose an enumeration $\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\dots$ of your well-ordering and define a map by setting:

$$\alpha_n \mapsto \sum_{k : \alpha_k < \alpha_n} \frac1{2^k} \in \mathbb R.$$